# Mysql query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, t1 and t2, t1 holds aliases and scores, while t2 holds aliases and their real names, I wish to build a query to get the scores,real names and aliases (example - desired results)

**t1**

```
alias - scores - tl_alias - tm_alias (column names)

tk - 96 - pp - jj
sp - 94 - pp - jj
```

**t2**

```
name - alias - role  (column names)

tom Koshy - tk - user  
shaun penn - sp - user  
peter pan - pp - tl  
john james - jj - tm
```

**Desired Result**

```
user_alias - user_name - scores - tl_alias - tl_name - tm_alias - tm_name (column labels)


tk - tom koshy - 96 - pp - peter pan - jj - john james
sp - shaun penn - 94 - pp - peter pan - jj - john james
```

**Current Results**

The below query gives me tl_name for all instances of t2.name in the query which I think is correct as per the query but what I would like to have is, the first instance of t2.name should show the user_name, then next instance should show the tl_name and then the tm_name

```
SELECT t1.alias,t2.name,t1.scores,t1.tl_alias,t2.name,t1.tm_alias,t2.name from t1 JOIN t2 on t1.tl_alias = t2.alias

tk - peter pan - 96 - pp - peter pan - jj - peter pan
sp - peter pan - 94 - pp - peter pan - jj - peter pan
```

The below does not work either

```
SELECT t1.alias,t2.name,t1.scores,t1.tl_alias,t2.name,t1.tm_alias,t2.name from t1 JOIN t2 on t1.tl_alias = t2.alias, t1.tm_alias = t2.alias
```

Comment: You need to join to t2 twice, once for each alias.

Comment: @Uueerdo , can you give a quick example on joining twice, I tried the below but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misspoke in my initial comment, you actually need to join to t2 *three* times, like so...

```
SELECT t1.alias AS user_alias, t2_u.name AS user_name
   , t1.scores
   , t1.tl_alias, t2_l.name AS tl_name
   , t1.tm_alias, t2_m.name AS tm_name
FROM t1 
   JOIN t2 AS t2_u on t1.alias = t2_u.alias
   JOIN t2 AS t2_l on t1.tl_alias = t2_l.alias
   JOIN t2 AS t2_m ON t1.tm_alias = t2_m.alias
;
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again, is it possible to do this with the AS , I have created a small CMS system, I do not have an option to add AS there

Comment: I think I will have to add the option to add AS there then :)

Comment: I have added the AS option, and when I run the above code, it just freezes my PC, I have tried it on 2 machines, are you sure there are no typos or anything missing in the code in the code

Comment: Try the query in a query browser like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin. If it has typo's, MySQL should reject it. If it runs quickly, you know it's your homegrown framework. If it is still slow, you probably want to consider indexing `t2` on it's `alias` field.

Comment: kewl that worked on phpmyadmin MySQL like a charm but does not work in phpmyadmin Raspbian MariaDB, will figure it out why it is not working in MariaDB, thanks champ

Answer (score 1):

use inner join  and sub-query

```
select t3.*,t2.name  from
(    
 select t1.alias,t2.name, t1.scores ,t1.tl_alias  from t1 join t2 on t1.alias =t2.alias
) as t3 join t2 on t3.tl_alias  =t2.tl_alias
```

or use  join with t2 for two times by using table alias

```
select t1.alias,t2.name, t1.scores ,t1.tl_alias,t3.name 
 from t1 join t2 on t1.alias =t2.alias
      join t2 as t3 on t1.tl_alias=t3.alias
```

Comment: looks complex, let me try this :)

Comment: @ManurajSebastian not complex just t2 use two times in join using table alias

Comment: @ManurajSebastian no this is not typo its table t2 alias for joining with diff column

Comment: ,sorry to bother you again, is it possible to do this with the AS , I have created a small CMS system, I do not have an option to add AS there